# Spring Cache Persistence in Kubernetes Deployment

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cache

Have seen a super weird issue in our **aws kubernetes cluster deployment** where the **in-memory spring cache** appeared to be persistent even after a rollout restart and pod deletion. Is that even possible for an argument sake? Deletion of a pod should have deleted the container which should thereby the underlying memory.

Please share your thoughts, as there is no logs associated to share except the observed behavior.

**Environment Details:**

```
Spring Boot 2.7.x
AWS EKS 1.21
Java 17
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring Cache is an abstraction that provides automatic integration with various persistence technologies besides a simple in-memory cache.
If you have redis configured, for example, and are using spring boot, a default redis caching will take place.